# error “ type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' ” flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Flutter ,  got the following error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' , any help, please?

'''
if(response.statusCode ==200)

```
    String jSonData = response.body;
    var decodeData = jsonDecode(jSonData) ;
    return decodeData;
```

'''

Comment: Write a code example. In this case your index is a `String` and you try to use it with a function that accept only `int`

Comment: Please your entire method.

Comment: Can you please add your model code and response

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `String jSonData`
The response that you are getting is not a String.

try changing your code to

```
 if(response.statusCode ==200) {
    final decodeData = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return decodeData;
}
```

this should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

the status code 200 is coming on int data type and you are trying to parse to to the  string check the data type agin and please add your full code still having doubt let me know